# A vector in a rotating frame. Find the rate of change of this vector ('particular step derivation')

Tags: reference-frames, vectors, rotational-kinematics

I am doing a project with the fundamental background not in my major. I am reading the following lecture:

[image]

How to get the green part?

Can anyone show me the detailed derivation or provide the note for reference?

(There might be similar questions; however I only want the specific derivation or explanation of some steps not the last result.)

Comment: The detailed derivation of the first expression can be  found in the book Classical Mechanics by Herbert Goldstein in the chapter "The Kinematics of Rigid Body Motion".
The second expression is obtained after applying the small angle approximation to $\cos\delta\theta$ and $\sin\delta\theta$, i.e., $\cos\delta\theta\approx 1$ and $\sin\delta\theta\approx\delta\theta$.

Comment: Also related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/103895/rotating-reference-frames , http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/135210/time-derivative-of-angular-velocity-in-rotating-reference-frame , and many others.

Comment: __Rotation of a vector :__  
http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/252942/rotation-of-a-vector/253390#253390

__Velocity in a turning reference frame :__
http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/67053/velocity-in-a-turning-reference-frame/252265#252265

Comment: Thank @Frobenius That link solves my problem. I mark my problem duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The first green part is the [Rodrigue's rotation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula).
- The second green part is a small angle approximation for $\delta \theta$.

Comment: Unless you remember the name it is difficult to search for it. Best guess would be to search for "Rotation About Arbitrary Axis".