# What is $2\dot{r}\dot{\theta}$?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism

I am in a classical mechanics class and we are currently working on Lagrangians. I notice that very often when working with an angular velocity the formula $2\dot{r}\dot{\theta}$ comes up. What is the physical meaning of this value?

Comment: Looks like something proportional to centripetal/centrifugal acceleration $v^2/r$.

Comment: It’s the coriolis force

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The two causes for the factor 2 in Coriolis effect](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/248850/)

Comment: [Near duplicate](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/248850)

Comment: Another [near duplicate](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/383)

Comment: It’s one of the terms in [acceleration expressed in polar coordinates](https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/University_Physics/Book%3A_Mechanics_and_Relativity_(Idema)/06%3A_General_Planar_Motion/6.02%3A_General_Planar_Motion_in_Polar_Coordinates).