# Scalar versus invariant in Newtonian mechanics

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, relative-motion, coriolis-effect, invariants

I looking up coriolis transport theorem for rotating refrence frames and while reading through this [derivation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/383/derivation-of-the-centrifugal-and-coriolis-force) he wrote:

> In Newtonian mechanics, scalar quantities must be invariant for any
>   given choice of frame,...

He is refering to the acceleration. I don't know the reasoning for that, but I know that it's clear for the length of the "vector from source to test point" which is scalar and invariant over transformation and rotation.

Question:

- Why is acceleration invariant over transformation and rotation?
- Why In Newtonian mechanics, must scalar quantities  be invariant for any given choice of frame?
- some rigorous math read for scalar vs invariant "hopfully doesn't
  include tensors".
- Some history read for scalar vs invariant.

Comment: The distance from the origin to a particular point is not invariant, since if you move the origin the distance is different. So it is probably a very limited meaning intended...

Comment: I meant difference vector from source to dist.

Comment: Scalar quantities aren't just invariant in Newtonian mechanics, they're invariant in relativistic physics too.

Comment: not after Lorentz transformation.